# Add new field to biblatex entries

Tags: biblatex

Many of the books I use are parts of series. `biblatex` gives you more fields to add bibliographic information to than BibTeX does, but it has no fields appropriate for the editor of a series. If I use the `EDITOR` field, the bibliography will (by default) print `edited by`, which doesn't give the right impression of what the role of the series editor is.

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to add a new field `SERIESEDITOR`, which will make `biblatex` by default print its content preceded by `Series edited by` *or* make sure that whatever is in `SERIESEDITOR` gets printed directly after the name of the series, such that is says something like `[Name of series], edited by [series editor]`. In other words, is there any way I can do this in the preamble of my document, without having to venture into writing new bibliography styles?

Comment: I guess there is some reason not to do it the obvious way which (I take it) involves adding a few strings to a `biblatex.cfg` and then using `editor` with `editortype` or the `a` `b` or `c` versions of same? (Maybe this wasn't available when this was asked?)

Comment: @cfr Obvious to whom? `:)` I know nothing about `biblatex.cfg`, plus I'm skeptical of messing with the internal files of `biblatex`.

Comment: Well, it's a config file. I just use the standard interface for it. That is, Biblatex is designed so that certain things can be extended according to need because nobody could anticipate, say, *all* possible relations between entries or *all* possible roles. At least, that's how I understand this bit of what my `*.cfg` does. (It does some other things which might count as messing with the internals, but not this, I don't think.)

Answer (score 21):

`biblatex 2.0+` and `biber 1.0+` allow you to define additional fields and entry types, but this is intended for style authors and can't be used in the document preamble.

With `biber`'s source map feature you can however use the field `serieseditor` and map it to a field defined in the default data model, such as `namea`. This existing field can then be printed in the bibliography macro that sets the `series` field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=serieseditor,fieldtarget=namea]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \ifnameundef{namea}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{namea}}%
  \newunit}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2 (and in combination with `biber`, version 1 or greater) `biblatex` allows you define any kind of additional field. Check out chapter 4.5.2 of the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: I did look there, but I didn't, and don't, understand what I need to do to make ``biblatex`` parse a field I've added to my entries.

Comment: To have `biblatex` parse it you must of course adapt the style files. For example, if you add a field `serieseditor`, you must look which parts of the .bbx/.cbx should handle this field and write the needed adaptation.