# How to automatically include PDFs from my bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I use the BIB list generated by Mendeley, with contains an item called "file" with the path to the PDF of each entry.

I need to generate a compilation of papers and I would like to do it automatically in the following manner.

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\fullcite{foo}
\includepdf{\readfilefrom{foo}}.
```

So, what I'm looking for is a function that given a bib item, it will return the path saved in the `file` entry of my bib file.

Example of bib entry:

```
@inproceedings{foo,
address = {Aachen, Germany},
author = {Masiero, Bruno },
booktitle = {DAGA},
file = {:D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Fels_2011_Equalization for Binaural Synthesis with Headphone.pdf:pdf},
month = mar,
title = {Equalization for Binaural Synthesis with Headphone},
year = {2011}
}
```

Some other examples of the file field would be:

```
file = {:D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Pelzer\_2010\_Study of Phase Reconstruction Methods Employed at Room Acoustic Simulation.pdf:pdf},

file = {:D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Pollow\_2010\_A review of the compressive sampling framework in the lights of spherical harmonics applications to distributed spherical arrays.pdf:pdf},

file = {::D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Pollow, Fels\_2011\_Design of a Fast Broadband Individual Head-Related Transfer Function Measurement System.pdf:pdf},

file = {:D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Qiu\_2009\_Two Listeners Crosstalk Cancellation System Modelled by Four Point Sources and Two Rigid Spheres.pdf:pdf},

file = {:D\:/Users/masiero/Documents/My Dropbox/Literature/pdf/Masiero, Ribeiro, Nascimento\_2008\_Transducer Placement Strategy for Active Noise Control of Power Transformers\_Fortschritte der Akustik -- DAGA.pdf:pdf},
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what should be included here: `\include` is for inputting `.tex` files containing chapters of a document. Do you want to include the PDF themselves or the links to the PDFs?

Comment: Could you add an example of a `.bib` entry?

Comment: I´m compiling the code with pdflatex and I have the article in PDF.
My example code was oversimplified.
But that can be made with \includepdf. 
Question is updated.

Comment: @bmasiero Uh! Those pesky accents. :(

Comment: @egreg I updated the examples with papers in English, all without the pesky nice accents. ;)

Comment: @bmasiero You realize that there's not much to do, if some of them has accented characters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you `file` field brings only the *exact location of a file without spaces*, a possible solution with [**`biblatex`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) and **`biber`** would be:

1. Remap (following [Audrey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65403/4427) to [Add new field to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65374/add-new-field-to-biblatex-entries?lq=1)) the `file` field into a custom field biber and biblatex can understand (e.g. `usera`);
2. Create a `bibmacro` that calls `includepdf` (from the [`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages) package);
3. Append that to `cite` bibmacro (or create a new cite command).

First, I created a `foo.pdf` file from the following `.tex` file (in my `/tmp/` dir):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Foooooooooo!
\end{document}
```

Then I created a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This is to create our dummy bib file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{foo,
    author = {A. Author},
    title = {Title},
    journal = {A Journal},
    volume = {x},
    year = {2012},
    file = {/tmp/foo.pdf}
    }
\end{filecontents}% end bib file
                  % (change the pdf location accordingly)

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}% I'm used to verbose style;
                                                  % with numeric, the result is weird.
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}% Loads the bib file created with filecontents (above)

% This changes a 'file' field into a 'usera' field which biber\biblatex can understand:
\DeclareSourcemap{% I took this from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65403/5872
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=file,fieldtarget=usera]
      }
    }
  }

\usepackage{pdfpages}% This package allows us to include pdf files (or pages)

% We create a bibmacro to include the pdf...
\newbibmacro{file}{%
  \iffieldundef{usera}{}{%
    \includepdf{\thefield{usera}}
  }}

\usepackage{xpatch}% This package allows us to patch (bib)macros

% ... and then we tell the 'cite' bibmacro to call it:
\xapptobibmacro{cite}%
  {\usebibmacro{file}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\cite{foo}

\end{document}
```

And here's the output (Sorry, I don't know how to handle these images very well yet, I tried to at least crop it):

[image: PDF from .bib file example]

**EDIT**: Instead of patching the `cite' bibmacro with`xpatch`, you can also define a new citation command, say:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}[]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}
   \usebibmacro{file}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fullcites}{\fullcite}{\multicitedelim}
```

Comment: It depends on the format of the field. I have some ideas, if the field ends with `:pdf`.

Comment: Henrique, unfortunately this workaround is not working for me.
It seems my problem is on the way Mendeley saves the files, containing spaces and that :pdf at the end, as can be seen in the examplary bib entry I just edited above.

Comment: @bmasiero Is the format always `:<PATH>:pdf`?

Comment: @bmasiero Yes, that's why I mentioned `l3regex` to egreg. You might also have problems when the file location contains spaces.

Comment: @egreg The format used by Mendeley is always
`file = {:<fullpath>:ext;:<fullpath>:ext}`

@henrique Yep, spaces are also a problem for `\includepdf`.

Comment: @bmasiero Are you meaning `:<path>,<space><filename>:ext`? This is the format in your example

Comment: @egreg Actually, the format is `{:<path><authors>_<year>_<title>.ext:ext}`.
Authors are separated by comma and space and the title also contains spaces.
Semicollom is used in case the entry has more than one file associated to it.

Comment: @bmasiero In order to provide a decent solution, some more examples of those fields are needed. Can you show some? Just edit your question; only the `file` fields are needed.