# How to show the file field with biblatex+biber?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` + `biber` with a `bib` file containing entries like this:

```
@article{pm2006,
  author={Pritsker, Matthew},
  title={The hidden dangers of historical simulation},
  journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
  year={2006},
  volume={30},
  number={2},
  pages={561-582},
  month={February},
  file={xpto.pdf}
}
```

I want to show the `file` field.
How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65403/5872)

Comment: @henrique The field `file` is already defined in BibLaTeX, but it is not used in the vast majority of existing styles. Indeed it is possible to use the map facilities of biber to map it to something used by an existing style.

Comment: @Guido Yes, but that seems too much of a hack, your approach is way better (I learned a lot with it!)

Answer (score 20):

The BibTeX field `file` is not support by the standard BibLaTeX styles.  A style supporting it is the `reading` one.

To use it in other styles, the first thing is to provide formatting instructions for it:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addcolon\space \url{#1}}
```

The second thing to do is to give instructions to print the field (and at the right position), this means to redefine some  existing bib macro to include the field in it. To print it at the end of an entry a possibility is to redefine the `finentry` bib macro.

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \finentry\addspace
  \printfield{file}%
  }
```

Another possibility would be to include the information in the block to print `URL` or `DOI`.

```
\newbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{file}
}
```

The code above could be refined to include a option (`file`) in the same way as the option for `doi`, `url` and `eprint`, namely:

```
\newbool{bbx:file}
```

to be activated by `\usepackage[file,...]{biblatex}`,  and the last line of the code above can be replaced by

```
\iftoggle{bbx:file}
  {\printfield{file}}
  {}
```

**EDIT** Solution using `\AtEveryBibitem`:

`\AtEveryBibitem` executes the code in its argument immediately after the item code. Thus using `\printfield{file}` would result that the file name will be printed before the content of the entry. However, one can append it at the end of the content of the driver. The content of the driver is  available with the control sequence `blx@bbx@<entrytype>`.  The command `\thefield{entrytype}` will give us the string needed. Thus, to print the file name at the end of a bib item, we can use the following instruction:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{\addspace\printfield{file}}}
```

Comment: Guido, I used your first possibility. It worked as I needed. My best guess was with \AtEveryBibitem which printed the file field as the first one. And that was not what I needed. Thank you so much! jbs

Comment: @jbs Glad it helped. You might consider to accept the answer, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: I tried to accept your answer, I read the post you sugested about accepting an answer, but I couldn't manage to accept it. I don't know if this is because I post the question without being registered to stackexchange. I register to accept your answer but the accept icon simply doesn't appear