# biblatex, using space in url doesnt work

Tags: biblatex, citing, url

when I try to use a space in an url, it displays %20 instead of space.
I looked for answers on the internet and found that the use of

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}%
```

should do the trick. It does, but at least for me not inside the bibliography.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}%
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{test}
\begin{document}
 \cite{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018}
 \url{C:/Test Folder/file}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}


@misc{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018,
 langid = {Englisch},
 title = {RCP-1600 series},
 url = {C:/Test Filder/file},
 shorttitle = {RCP-1600},
 date = {2018-01-15},
 author = {MEAN\textasciitilde{}WELL}
}
```

any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The correct URL is `file:///C:/Test%20Folder/file` (without any space). See [this documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/).

Comment: thanks for the info, but thats not what I want it to loke like ob the paper

Comment: A URL/URI can't contain spaces (see [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)).

Comment: I know. I don't want to create a valid URL i want to show the file path to the reader of a printed document (the file is on a cd given with the document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could redefine the url bibmacro to use urlraw instead of url:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}%
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{test}

\renewbibmacro*{url}{\printfield{urlraw}}
\begin{document}
 \cite{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018}
 \url{C:/Test Folder/file}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh beaten by 18 seconds ... And just when I was hoping to test the [picture hypothesis](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7758/35864) you add a picture...

Comment: @moewe ;-). But urlraw was my suggestion ... https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/159

Comment: Come to think of it I like your solution slightly better than mine, it would be even better with `\printfield[url]{urlraw}` instead of just `\printfield{urlraw}`.

Comment: @moewe if one wants a link (I personally avoid to many links normally) one should probably do `\DeclareFieldFormat{urlraw}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\href{\thefield{url}}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}` so that the encoded url is used for the link.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think about the link target ... in which case we would be back at my answer ...

Comment: unfortunately both answers result on my PC in not displaying the url at all :(

Comment: Then your biblatex is perhaps outdated. urlraw is rather new.

Answer (score 5):

`C:/Test Folder/file` is quite an unusual URL for a bibliography, but of course that may just be for the example. If it is not, though, you may want to look into the `file` field, it is not used by any of the standard styles, but it would be the semantically sound decision.

Biber escapes URLs into percent encoding. If you don't want that you can show the `urlraw` field instead, see [How to disable percent-encoding in URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355136/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018,
  langid     = {english},
  title      = {RCP-1600 series},
  url        = {C:/Test Filder/file},
  shorttitle = {RCP-1600},
  date       = {2018-01-15},
  author     = {MEAN\textasciitilde{}WELL}
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{\thefield{urlraw}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
 \cite{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018}
 \url{C:/Test Folder/file}
 \raggedright
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The URL in the bibliography now displays as <code>C:/Test Folder/file</code>]

You can be a bit safer and link to the encoded version while showing the unencoded version with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \nolinkurl
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
     {\thefield{urlraw}}}}
```

Note that the `langid` field should contain a language name known to `babel` or `polyglossia`. `Englisch` is not a valid language name in that context, you probably want `english`.

Comment: follow up question, I decided to use


    \DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\mkbibacro{file:}\addcolon\space#1}

    \renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
 \finentry\addspace
 \printfield{file}%
    }

but now all my umlauts are missing.
(I also added \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}) to my MWE

Comment: @Jannis.D That is ... odd. Can you ask a new question about that, please. Include the `.log` file (you can upload it to a text-sharing website such as GitLab Snippes, GitHub Gists, pastebin, ... if it is too long to be included here) and a screenshot of the output you get.

Comment: I will ask a new question. I got it so far that it displays strange looking characters.
Thanks for so much help!

Answer (score 3):

A file path can't be a valid URL. So, in your bib entry, don't use the `url` field to store a file path!

## First solution *(using `eprint` and `eprinttype` fields)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018,
 langid = {Englisch},
 title = {RCP-1600 series},
 eprint = {C:/Test Folder/file},
 eprinttype= {raw},
 shorttitle = {RCP-1600},
 date = {2018-01-15},
 author = {MEAN\textasciitilde{}WELL}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:raw}{%
  Path\addcolon\space\texttt{#1}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
 \cite{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018}

 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second Solution *(using `file` field)*

(form [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82135/14500))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018,
 langid = {Englisch},
 title = {RCP-1600 series},
 file = {C:/Test Folder/file},
 shorttitle = {RCP-1600},
 date = {2018-01-15},
 author = {MEAN\textasciitilde{}WELL}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{%
  \bibstring{file}\addcolon\space\texttt{#1}%
}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \finentry\addspace
  \printfield{file}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
 \cite{mean_well_rcp-1600_2018}

 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then I would go all the way and use the semantically more apt `file` field, `eprint` does not seem to be much better than `url` in terms of abuse.

Comment: @moewe Done... !