# Enabling double way for bibliography with \url: Both bibtex and biblatex (biber)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, urls

I am trying to make a document to accept both `bibtex` and `biblatex` (during different compilations of course) and I have a problem because:

1. In `bibtex` I have to add `\url` command inside every url (really many entries)
2. But biblatex doesn't accept this (already there and so, it supposes it is a part of my url) and giving unwanted results.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% \UseBibLaTex is a variable that if is less than 1 the document 
% will have to compiled with `bibTeX`... else with biber
\def\UseBibLaTeX{0}
% ``url'' package is used in order to make LaTeX to break the urls 
% in places like the bibliography combined with the next (upcoming) 
% command
%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu

\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\newcommand\myurl[1]{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{{\footnotesize URL:}\space%\expandafter%\noexpand
\myurl{#1}}
\addbibresource{myBib.bib}
\else
% ``natbib'' package offers the bigger ammount possibilities in bibliography
% formating
\let\myurl\url
\usepackage{natbib}
\fi


\begin{filecontents*}{myBib.bib}
@Article{cite1,
title={One Article with a url that has to break both in bibtex and biblatex},
author={Someone NotMe and Someother Me},
year={2018},
month={10},
url={\url{http://A-long-URL-that-has-to-break-through-lines-and-biber-has-to-ignore-the-\textbackslash url-command}},
doi={http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphys1170}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Double Functionality about Bibliography}
\author{Konstantinos Leledakis}
\date{October 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}
\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\printbibliography
\else
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{sloppypar}
  \bibliography{myBib}
\end{sloppypar}
\fi



\end{document}
```

The output of the above code, is as expected... but if I change 
the command `\def\UseBibLaTeX{0}` to `\def\UseBibLaTeX{1}` I get (an expected as a noob about biber but...) unwanted result:

[image]

Already tried some things like `\noexpand` or `\expandafter` that are commented in my code but could not make it work as I wanted.

Comment: As far as `biblatex` is concerned the `url` field *must not* contain `\url` or anything else other than the raw URL. I thought most `.bst` files (that support URLs) would handle the situation similarly.

Comment: @moewe... I understood that, but tried to change the way that handles this field (possibly only its format and thus failed). I suppose there is a way, at least change the `bibtex` way (and adding this command to every url field autamaticaly) if `biblatex` way can not adjusted. I tried with changes in `biblatex` first because I thought is more powerful to handle such situations

Comment: I could accept a new kind of entry too that will be added there like note, but trying to avoid it. The final result I am after is just to not need to change the bibliography file from compilation to compilation... And just preffer to be able to use the already existing fields in bibliography files (with or without addition of `\url` command) without changes... But if not posible, I am going to add them as a note

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` expects the `url` field to contain the URL and the URL only. No additional markup like `\url{...}`, no escaping of special characters, nothing, just the verbose URL.

The problem you are seeing is that Biber applies percent encoding to the URL and this messes up your `\url{...}` wrapper. (There are ways to get rid of the percent encoding, see [biblatex, using space in url doesnt work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443599/35864), [How to disable percent-encoding in URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355136/35864), [Scandinavian letters in Biblatex URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451117/35864), but that would not really help here.)

Luckily most `.bst` files that support a dedicated URL field also handle URLs in a way that does not require you to add `\url{...}` or additional commands; like `biblatex` they expect the raw URL.

The exact handling of the URL with BibTeX depends on the `.bst` style you use.  `agsm` uses the command `\harvardurl` which you can redefine. Unfortunately, there is no general consensus amongst all `.bst` as to how URLs are handled. Many `.bst` files just use `\url{...}` directly (notably the standard `natbib` styles and `urlbst`),  a few like `agsm` have a dedicated command.

*edit:* I originally understood the use of `\myurl` in the MWE as an attempt to uniformly change the URL format for both `biblatex` and BibTeX styles (possibly independent of other `\url`s displayed in the document). If that was indeed the aim of `\myurl`, you need to know how your `.bst` files handles URLs and redefine the commands involved accordingly. It would be nigh-impossible to pull this off in a style-agnostic fashion. If, on the other hand, you only intended to fix the undesired output of the `biblatex` URLs in the MWE and you generally want the URLs to be displayed "normally", then there is no need for `\myurl` at all and you can probably just use the styles as they are. See the edit history for the first version of the answer.

Either way, `natbib`'s definition of `agsm`'s `\harvardurl` should probably be tweaked a bit to allow for all kinds of URLs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\UseBibLaTeX{0}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}


\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\else
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}
\fi

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{cite1,
  title  = {One Article with a url that has to break both in bibtex and biblatex},
  author = {Someone NotMe and Someother Me},
  year   = {2018},
  url    = {http://A-long-URL-that-has-to-break-through-lines-and-biber-has-to-ignore-the-\textbackslash url-command},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\ifnum\UseBibLaTeX>0
  \printbibliography
\else
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, will it will work for more styles in bibtex? (I am going to accept it anyway... but would like to be a little more flexible between styles if possible)

Comment: @koleygr It depends on the `.bst` style. For starters, it won't work if the `.bst` file does not support a `url` field. The code with `\harvardurl` only works for `.bst` files that use `\harvardurl`. Depending on the exact code for URLs that your style may use, this would have to be tweaked slightly. Given that there is no universal standard for URLs in `.bst` files, that is about as general as it gets, sorry.

Comment: Thanks... I am somehow disappointed for this... because the style was just an example and I meant to use this way to have more ways to print the bibliography and not less chances to work... Of course if url doesn't supported it will be ignored and this is not a problem since I will have decided to use the style... I have to change the code (your \let) to something supported by my specific bibtex style if any. (Remove the `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}` command since doesn't do something useful now . Also `\myurl` doensn's needed since `\url` would be enough... but your point is clear). Thanks again

Comment: @koleygr Well if you don't want to mess with the output the styles give you by default, you don't need `\myurl` and all the redefinitions. In that case most `.bst` files with URL support will just work. I thought the whole point of `\myurl` was to be able to manipulate the URL output uniformly for both `biblatex` and BibTeX?

Comment: @koleygr I think I misunderstood your `\myurl`, see the updated answer, please.

Comment: in my original code I used `\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu` since it is needed for breaking the urls for my real (extended) document and it works with bibtex perfectly with your `\let` command combined with `sloppypar` too. Without your \let I can not compile with bibtex... Thus your \let command makes the trick for me and needed there. I just have to add `sloppypar` in the biber way too

Comment: Thanks @moewe... I just show your edit. (Thought that I would be notified about the edit...) Deleting last comment and my edit in the post