# Error with URL in bibliography, TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, url

When I try to add the following Website to my bibliography I get an error, that TeX capacity is exceeded. I would be very thankful for your help. I integrated it into a file with JabRef. After this, you will find my main file. If you need anything else, feel free to ask.

```
@Misc{uni.utah.mm,
author = {Peter Alfeld},
note   = {[Online; Stand 10.08.2020]},
title  = {The Mandelbrot Set.},
url    = "\url{https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html}",
}
```

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[headsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[bottom, perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=small}
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{%
    #1%
    \\\hspace{\linewidth}%
    \textbf{Quelle:} #2%
  }%
}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={Maturitätsarbeit - Die Darstellung Mandelbrot-artiger Mengen im dreidimensionalen Raum},
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\makeatletter
\def\thickhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \thickarrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xthickhline}
\def\@xthickhline{\ifx\reserved@a\thickhline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\thickarrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{8}
\newlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}{2\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeindex

\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\small \rightmark}
\ofoot{\small \pagemark} 
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\font\myfont=cmr16
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{singlespace}
\subject{\large Maturitätsarbeit}
\title{\Large Die Darstellung Mandelbrot-artiger Mengen im dreidimensionalen Raum}
\end{singlespace}
\maketitle
\hrule
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addsec{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{mm}[MM]{Mandelbrot-Menge}
\end{acronym}
\pagebreak

\input{vorwort.tex}
\pagebreak
\input{einleitung.tex}
\newpage
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

The exact error message is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].\@makeother #1->\catcode `#112\relax .../~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html}}
```

Comment: For most BibTeX styles you should not use `\url` inside a `url` field. `url    = "https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html",` should be enough. (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455698/35864, which came up again just a few minutes ago.)

Comment: Unrelated, but for most uses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is more than enough and `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` is overkill. Since `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` loads `ucs` you don't need to say `\usepackage{ucs}` in any case. The problem with `utf8x`/`ucs` is that it is incompatible with some packages.

Comment: @moewe is exactly right. I've just tried it and it works. This has to be changed in your bib-file: `url = {https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html},`.

Comment: @moewe, wouldn't it be better to switch over to biblatex and use `style=numeric, sorting=none` as options? Would this achieve the same thing?

Comment: @phil-elkabat Well, I wouldn't outright say that switching to `biblatex` would be 'better' (and I would be biased anyway). There are certainly good reasons to switch to `biblatex` (`biblatex` is usually easier to customise, supports Unicode properly, ...), but there are also equally good reasons to stick with BibTeX (publishers and the arXiv are not too keen on `biblatex`, there are many, many ready-made BibTeX styles out there, ...). It all depends on the specific situation. ...

Comment: ... You could certainly achieve a qualitatively similar result, but getting the exact same output as `\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}` with `biblatex` would take some work.

Comment: @moewe, thank you for this excellent explanation! I'm eager to learn and this community is among the best things that LaTeX-wise ever happened to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first BibTeX styles predate the standardisation of the URL protocol by a few years. This means that the base BibTeX styles do not have a dedicated `url` field. Newer styles may support a `url` field, but the exact implementation and handling of that field is not uniform across styles.

With most styles that support a `url` field, however, the rule is to give the URL without change and without additional markup, since they interface with `url`/`hyperref` (or can more or less easily be made to interface with these packages). You don't need to wrap the URL in `\url{...}` when it is given in the `url` field and you do not need to escape otherwise special characters like `%` or `_`.

This is true for your style `unsrtdin`, which interfaces with `url` and `hyperref` and accepts URLs as-is. Just give the URL as

```
url = {https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html},
```

You may have to delete the temporary `.bbl` file after you fixed the `.bib` file, because the old code from the unfixed `.bib` file may live on in the `.bbl` file. (The procedure of generating a bibliography and the role of the `.bbl` file is explained wonderfully in [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) if you want to know more.)

In full (note that the MWE crates the `.bib` file via `filecontents`, that is just to make the example self-contained, in a real-world document the `.bib` file would live outside the `.tex` file)

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{uni.utah.mm,
  author = {Peter Alfeld},
  note   = {[Online; Stand 10.08.2020]},
  title  = {The Mandelbrot Set},
  url    = {https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{uni.utah.mm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Alfeld, Peter: The Mandelbrot Set. https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/math/mandelbrot/mandelbrot.html. – [Online; Stand 10.08.2020]]

It should be noted that `unsrtdin` (as part of the [`din1505` style bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/din1505)) implements a DIN 1505-2-compliant citation style. The German standard DIN 1505-2 (from 1984) was replaced by DIN ISO 690 in 2013 and makes some (in my eyes at least) questionable typographic decisions. If you are not forced to use that style, you may want to look for something else.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for your answer. I do have the .bib file separate. I did remove the `\url{...}` but I still have the same error...

Comment: @JanHochstrasser Did you remove the `.bbl` file before you recompiled? (The bibliography data is not directly read by LaTeX, instead the helper program BibTeX reads the `.bib` file and generates LaTeX-readable data in the `.bbl` file. The `.bbl` file is then read and typeset by LaTeX. See more in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. That means that if there is an error in the `.bib` file it may hang around in the `.bbl` file even after it has been fixed. In that case it helps to delete the `.bbl` and probably also `.aux` files and compile again.)

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now I could solve my problem and can continue to write my paper.

Comment: @major.hph If the answer helped you solve ypour problem you may want to consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. That will mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I am new to StackExchange and didn't know.