# Append a custom (BibLaTeX) field to one defined in the data model, preserving bibstring interpolation

Tags: biblatex

I want to make use of a custom field in my `bib` file, that is not defined in my BibLaTeX data model. I wish to map this field via the usual `\DeclareSourcemap` construct, as explained in [§4.5.3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), to one defined in my data model, but also *already in use*.

Specifically, I have a `@Patent` entry containing the `type` field, which I have set to the BibLaTeX-defined `patrequs` bibstring. I additionally use the custom field `appnumber`, to encode the USPTO application number (I already use `number` for the USPTO patent number).

Since `appnumber` is not defined in my data model, and I wish to obviate having to manually do so, I want to [map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65403/134641) this to be *appended* to the end of the *interpolated bibstring* that my `type` would otherwise expand to.

It seems that this requires two `\step` commands. The following works, but appends prior to bibstring interpolation, which is perhaps obvious, but not what I wish to accomplish.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \pertype{patent}
            \step[fieldsource=appnumber]
            \step[fieldset=type, origfieldval, append]
        }
    }
}
```

This yields, `patrequsNN/XXX,XXX` instead of the desired, `U.S. patent request NN/XXX,XXX`.

---

Please find a [sample `@Patent` entry](http://www.see-out.com/sandramau/bibpat.html) (adapted from Sandra Mau's webpage, pretending that the US patent has yet to be granted) and an example of desired output below, as a MWE (and [available on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/mxffrwmzqpfb)):

```
@Patent{EHLINGER:2006:biblatex,
 author = {EHLINGER, JR., Philip Charles},
 title = {Device for the treatment of hiccups},
 year = {2006},
 month = {06},
 day = {13},
 number = {7062320},
 kind   = {B2},
 appnumber = {10/684,114},
 type   = {patrequs},
 url = {http://www.patentlens.net/patentlens/patent/US_7062320/},
 IPC_class = {A61N 1/04},
 US_class = {607  2},
}
```

With the above `bib` file saved as `mwe.bib`, the following should (depending upon one's style and other configurations) reproduce output similar to the below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=biblatex-cse, autopunct, autocite=superscript, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
     \map{  % clear patent scope, obviating output of redundant info. for US patents
       \pertype{patent}
       \step[fieldset=location, null]
       \step[fieldset=kind, null]  % we include the USPTO kind codes, but do not use them
       % we use the field "appnumber" to store the USPTO application number
       % we simply map it to be appended to the "type" field, in the standard data model
       % Adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454008/134641
       \step[fieldsource=appnumber]
       \step[fieldset=type, origfieldval, append]
     }
  }
}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{EHLINGER:2006:biblatex}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: pdfLaTeX-rendered output of the above full citation.]

Whereas, I would like something akin to (perhaps also with some better punctuation to demarcate the `appnumber` from the `number`):

> EHLINGER JR. PC. 2006. Device for the treatment of hiccups. U.S. patent request 10/684,114 7062320.

---

Might anyone be able to fix this such that (1) the append occurs (or is equivalent to) the result after bibstring interpolation, (2) easily adds a space between the fields (i.e. without my having to modify the underlying style), *or* (3) suggests some viable alternative to properly encode and typeset the USPTO application number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why does the map not work?

Biber knows nothing about `biblatex`'s bibstrings. So it does not know that `patrequs` expands to "U.S. patent request". The bibstring is only 'expanded' by `biblatex` at the very last minute by virtue of

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}
```

That means that `biblatex` takes the contents of the `type` field as produced by Biber and checks if it coincides with the name of a bibstring (as `patrequs` would), if that is the case the corresponding bibstring is printed, if not the text is printed as is.

So `type = {patrequs},` expands to 'U.S. patent request'. To all intents and purposes, your mapping turns

```
type      = {patrequs},
appnumber = {10/684,114},
```

into

```
type      = {patrequs10/684,114},
```

Unfortunately `patrequs10/684,114` is not a known bibstring, so the text gets printed verbatim and the bibstring is not expanded.

## How can I get it to work?

### Just print `appnumber`

The best solution in my book would be to modify the style you use to print `appnumber` in the appropriate place and be done with it.

Since `appnumber` is not a known field in the data model that would necessarily require a custom `.dbx` file. See [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864). I admit that looks like a bit of work.

You could avoid the `.dbx` file if you remap the field to a reserved special field such as `usera`, but you would still have to tell the style to use it.

### A *terrible* hack

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
     \map{
       \pertype{patent}
       \step[fieldset=location, null]
     }
     \map{
       \pertype{patent}
       \step[fieldsource=appnumber, final]
       \step[fieldsource=type, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, replace=\regexp{\\ifbibstring\{$1\}\{\\bibstring\{$1\}\}\{$1\}\x{20}}]
       \step[fieldsource=appnumber]
       \step[fieldset=type, origfieldval, append]
     }
  }
}
```

Essentially recreates the field format that expands the bibstring in the sourcemap and lets

```
type      = {patrequs},
appnumber = {10/684,114},
```

come out as

```
type = {\ifbibstring{patrequs}{\bibstring{patrequs}}{patrequs} 10/684,114}
```

But this is truly atrocious.